# Beautiful Soup not returning anything I expected

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, find

**Background:**
Following along with a Udemy tutorial which is parsing some information from Bing.
It takes in a user input and uses that as a parameter to search Bing with, returning all the `href` links it can find on the first page

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as re

search = input("Enter what you wanna search: \n")
params = {"q": search}
r = re.get("https://www.bing.com/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find("ol",{"id":"b_results"})
links = results.findAll("li",{"class": "b_algo"})


for item in links:
    item_text = item.find("a").text
    item_href = item.href("a").attrs["href"]

    if item_text and item_href:
        print(item_text)
        print(item_href)

    else:
        print("Couldn't find 'a' or 'href'")
```

**Problem:**
It returns nothing. The code obviously works for him. I get no errors as I've checked the `id` and `class` names to see if they've been changed on bing itself since the video was made but they are still the same

```
"ol",{"id":"b_results"}
"li",{"class": "b_algo"}
```

Any ideas? I'm a complete noob to web scraping but intermediate to Python.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code needs a bit of reworking.

First of all, you need `headers` otherwise `Bing` (correctly) thinks you're a bot and it's not returning the `HTML`.

Then, you need to check if the anchors are not `None` and, say, have at least `http` in the `href`.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36",
}
page = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/search?", headers=headers, params={"q": "python"}).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

anchors = soup.find_all("a")
for anchor in anchors:
    if anchor is not None:
        try:
            if "http" in anchor["href"]:
                print(anchor.getText(), anchor["href"])
        except KeyError:
            continue
```

Output:

```
Welcome to Python.org https://www.python.org/
Diese Seite übersetzen http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?ref=SERP&br=ro&mkt=de-DE&dl=de&lp=EN_DE&a=https%3a%2f%2fwww.python.org%2f
Python Downloads https://www.python.org/downloads/
Windows https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
Python for Beginners https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/
About https://www.python.org/about/
Documentation https://www.python.org/doc/
Community https://www.python.org/community/
Success Stories https://www.python.org/success-stories/
News https://www.python.org/blogs/
Python (Programmiersprache) – Wikipedia https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28Programmiersprache%29
Wikipedia https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28Programmiersprache%29
CC-BY-SA-Lizenz http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
Python lernen - Python Kurs für Anfänger und Fortgeschrittene https://www.python-lernen.de/
Python 3.9.0 (64bit) für Windows - Download https://python.de.uptodown.com/windows
Python-Tutorial: Tutorial für Anfänger und Fortgeschrittene https://www.python-kurs.eu/kurs.php
Mehr zu python-kurs.eu anzeigen https://www.python-kurs.eu/kurs.php
Python (Programmiersprache) – Wikipedia https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28Programmiersprache%29
Python (Programmiersprache) - Wikipedia https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28Programmiersprache%29
```

By the way, what course is this, because scraping search engines is not easy?

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for your well-explained answer. The bot prevention measure might also explain why my selenium app to automate some Facebook messages isn't working either so perhaps 2 birds one stone here!

https://www.udemy.com/course/python-complete/ <------ Python course. The content creator originally was to use Google in the course but he couldn't get it to work so he switched to Bing. 

Question for you: Why did my code work on the Udemy course videos? As a note: The course is 4 years old. Is the code just outdated? 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

*This answer complements the [baduker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65158533/15164646) solution.*

First of all, yes, the code from that Udemy course could be outdated. Especially if it shows what selectors/HTML elements they used to extract certain data.

Some of the selectors are changed a few times on Bing.

As [baduker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65158533/15164646) said, it's because Bing detects that it's a script that sends a request. It simply detects because the [default `requests` user-agent is `python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) so when you make a request, Bing sees that the user-agent from that request is `python-requests` thus unusual.

To override the default user-agent we can pass a new user-agent to [custom-made request headers](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers). [Check what's your user-agent](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/).

Additionally, you can [rotate user-agents](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents) which will reduce the chance of being blocked a little more. You can also play around by passing different device user-agent such as desktop, tablet, or mobile.

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

search = input('Enter what you wanna search: ')

params = {'q': search}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

html = requests.get('https://www.bing.com/search', params=params, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

for result in soup.select('.b_algo h2'):
    link = result.select_one('a')['href']
    print(link)
```

Outputs (only links from organic results, not from the knowledge graph, related searches, etc):

```
Enter what you wanna search: minecraft
https://www.minecraft.net/
https://classic.minecraft.net/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmB9b5njVbA
https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/minecraft/
https://nl.ccm.net/download/downloaden-34090900-minecraft
https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/minecraft/11356
https://www.funnygames.nl/spel/minecraft.html
https://spele.nl/minecraft-games/
https://www.youtube.com/user/TeamMojang
```

---

If you don't want to deal with bypassing blocks or maintaining your code, have a look at [Bing Search API](https://serpapi.com/bing-organic-results) from SerpApi.

Example code:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

search = input('Enter what you wanna search: ')

params = {
    'api_key': '<your-serpapi-api-key>',
    'device': 'desktop',
    'engine': 'bing',
    'q': search
    # other parameters
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
    print(result['link'])
```

Outputs:

```
Enter what you wanna search: minecraft
https://www.minecraft.net/
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/minecraft/id479516143
https://classic.minecraft.net/
https://education.minecraft.net/en-us/mobile
```

Answer (score -1):

your script is working fine. If you look carefully to the requests answer (e.g. save `r.text` into a file), you'll see the answer is full of javascript.

Following this method, you'll see that the body is full of `<script>` balises:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<script>(...)</script>
<script>(...)</script>
<script>(...)</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I suggest to try another website, or use Selenium. Did Udemy really ask to try to scrape bing.com ?